# forced to keep on reinstalling Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I'm so feed up with Ubuntu 14.04.
This is really annoying. After each computer shutdown and turning it ON my WiFi is not working and I am forced to reinstall drivers from this package:

```
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And after that:

```
modprobe -r wl; modprobe wl;
```

This is the only package that is working. This was not an issue 2 or 3 months ago. So I'm asking kindly: WTF Ubuntu developers? Also Google Chrome (Chromium as well) is breaking often but this is other issue, but that's why I am feed up with this OS.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT 1:**

I've removed this .deb. While triggering the deb file I've noticed those notices:

> An older version of "bwmwl-kernel-source" is available in your normal software channels. Only install this file if you trust the origin.
>
> This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware.

**EDIT 2:**

```
less /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | grep blacklist
```

Output:

```
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
#blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Second command:

```
ls /etc/modprobe.d
alsa-base.conf          blacklist.conf           blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf  broadcom-sta-dkms.conf  iwlwifi.conf      vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf  blacklist.conf~          blacklist-modem.conf        blacklist-watchdog.conf      dkms.conf               mlx4.conf
blacklist-bcm43.conf    blacklist-firewire.conf  blacklist-oss.conf          broadcom-sta-common.conf     fbdev-blacklist.conf    modesetting.conf
```

**EDIT 3:**

I am pasting output from commands that chili555 asked me to trigger.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10825313/

Only one command failed:

```
iwconfig  >>  wifi.txt
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**IMPORTANT PS**: My coworker told my that his facing similar problem with Lenovo laptop  on windows 8 :/ In his case turning on plane mode and turning it off solves the problem. But why few months ago I was not having such troubles?

Comment: Does the wireless come to life if you simply do: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: It didn't because the command resolved with an answer: no such device (or similar). But after some drivers installation I was able to make it work. (Thank God for tethering) :)

Comment: So, solved? Or do you still need assistance?

Comment: I did not solved the issue. I described the earlier events due to Your question. 
I was unable to `modproble wl`. The driver hasn't detect the device but device is here and is still working (I am writing this Via my WiFi connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the package you are installing, `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` is the default for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; please see here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/bcmwl-kernel-source

In the dash, please open Software & Updates, select Updates and be certain that *trusty-security* and *trusty-updates* are checked. Then, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

I wonder if *wl* is blacklisted. Please run and post:

```
ls /etc/modprobe.d
tail -n10 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Please reboot when, presumably, the wireless is not working. Run the following commands in order to gather diagnostics:

```
lsmod | grep wl  >  wifi.txt
sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | head -n9  >>  wifi.txt
sudo dpkg -s dkms | head -n9  >>  wifi.txt
dmesg | grep -e wl -e wlan  >>  wifi.txt
iwconfig  >>  wifi.txt
rfkill list all  >>  wifi.txt
cat /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf  >> wifi.txt
cat /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf  >> wifi.txt
```

Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Give us the link in an edit.

Although the module *b43* is blacklisted twice (!!), it is still loading. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. If there is any reference to b43, ssb or bcma in the file, remove it. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Do the same with the file /etc/rc.local. If you are in any doubt about what you are removing, post your file and I'll be happy to help.

Reboot and tell us if the wireless works as expected.

Comment: I've triggered commands:

Output: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of bcmwl-kernel-source is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-31 linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.`

Comment: OK. After removing the package and connecting via tethering, I've managed to run those commands... No use :/ There is no WiFi after reboot and sudo modprobe wl does nothing. There is no WLAN Interface at the ubuntu bar. Also, please read my "edit 1" at the question. Maybe this will give You a hint.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Please see my edit 2 :D

Comment: Please see my further edit above.

Comment: Edited + important info below my EDIT #3:)

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: There is only one reference of b43 in /etc/modules - I mean there WAS :)
I am currently waiting for some time to restart my pc :)
Thank You for helping me so far and I hope that we are heading to the solution.  :)

Comment: Although still getting system error: 
after rebooting a message appears and after Sending report I've got a note: The bug is already reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta/+bug/1388080


But it's not Your concern anymore :) Thank You for Your help chili555. :) The case is closed!